# cuda error MSB3721 exited with code 2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile my first CUDA 5.0 project I took the template sample.  I have not gotten it to compile it yet and as it shows two errors, I have compared the project settings with those of the template project and they appear to be consistent so I'm stumped.  Here are my two errors.

The first occurs when I try to call my kernwl it marks the `'<<<'`

> Error 32  error : expected an expression  D:\Virtualbox
>   Data\Assembla\gul\antares
>   software\AntaresVisualizerCuda\AntaresVisualizerCuda\kernel.cu    584

Its possible that thar would be fixed by solving the next error:

> Error 33  error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU
>   Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin\nvcc.exe"
>   -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin"  -I"./" -I"C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA
>   Samples\v5.0\C\common\inc" -I"C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA
>   Samples\v5.0\shared\inc" -I"C:\fltk-1.3.0\include" -I"C:\Program
>   Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include" -I"C:\Program
>   Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include" -I"C:\Program
>   Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir
>   "Debug" -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile  -g   -DWIN32 -DWIN32
>   -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -D_WINDOWS -D_MBCS -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MTd  " -o "Win32/Debug/kernel.cu.obj"
>   "D:\Virtualbox Data\Assembla\gul\antares
>   software\AntaresVisualizerCuda\AntaresVisualizerCuda\kernel.cu""
>   exited with code 2.   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA
>   5.0.targets   498

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: You have a syntax error at line 584 of kernel.cu -- please at least include that line of code in your question...

Comment: Voting to close since OP has not added more information even though they have been back on the site since posting.

Comment: Please update your question to contain the relevant code. Without it we cannot help you with your problem. I have by now voted to close your question. If you update your question to make it a proper one, I would be more than willing to reopen it, should it be closed by that time.

Comment: all I'm doing at line 584 is:

tracePixel<<< gridP, threads >>>(d_screenOrigin, u_unit, d_u_dir, v_unit, d_v_dir, d_cam_pos, d_minpoint, d_maxpoint, gridLength, min, scale, d_grid, d_buffer,);

where tracepixel is a function marked __global__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your kernel call within the comments looks like this:

```
tracePixel<<< gridP, threads >>>(d_screenOrigin, u_unit, d_u_dir, v_unit, d_v_dir, d_cam_pos, d_minpoint, d_maxpoint, gridLength, min, scale, d_grid, d_buffer,);
```

If that is indeed what you have and not a typo, then there is an extra ',' after `d_buffer` which should not be there. Either that or you're missing an argument.

Comment: Yep I apparently I was thrown off by the error and the call running off screen thanks!